# how to use MaxUnpool1d from pytorch library in convolution autoencoder?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, autoencoder

I want to build a Convolution AutoEncoder using Pytorch library in python.
All of the examples have no MaxUnpool1d.

The architecture I want to build should be like:

```
class autoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
            self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
                                 nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=64 ,kernel_size=16 , stride=3),
                                 nn.ReLU(True),
                                 nn.MaxPool1d(4),
                                 nn.Conv1d(64, 128 ,8, 3),
                                 nn.ReLU(True),
                                 nn.MaxPool1d(4), 
                                 )

            self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
                                 nn.MaxUnpool1d(4),
                                 nn.ConvTranspose1d(in_channels =128, out_channels =64 , kernel_size =8, stride= 3),
                                 nn.ReLU(True),
                                 nn.MaxUnpool1d(4),
                                 nn.ConvTranspose1d(64, 1 ,16, 3),
                                 nn.Tanh()
                                 )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.encoder(x)
        x = self.decoder(x)
        return x
```

To make it work I should provide indices for the MaxUnpool1d layer.
How do I use it for the current architecture and also making the input size equals to the output?

Thanks.